# escape string db2

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2, ejs

I have `"` and `'` in my string that I am sending to my database. however, it is reading it as an ending string delimiter, which makes sense. so in my nodejs, I found something like `mysql_real_escape_string`, but I am using db2 sql queries, so I don't think this will work. anyone have any ideas? thanks :)

query:

```
 "insert into PRODUCTS ( ITEM, DESCRIPTION, PRICE, SIZES, IMAGE ) VALUES ('" +
  req.query.item +
  "', '" +
  req.query.description +
  "', '" +
  req.query.price +
  "', '" +
  size +
  "', '" +
  image_url +
  "' )";
```

need to change `description` to be allowed to have `ex. here is a quote from John. "you've had better days"`

thanks :)

Comment: Your problem is that your are not using parameters.  Then string delimiters would be a non-issue.

Comment: could you explain more or show example of how to do this please :)

Comment: That code is wide open to SQL Injection. Use parameterized SQL instead. Don't escape strings.